# Git commit or checkout not working

Tags: git, git-bash, git-for-windows

I am trying to checkout my staged file changes using git-bash. But it shows me a fatal error

> Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
>   an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
>   are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
>   may have crashed in this repository earlier:
>   remove the file manually to continue.

So, I deleted the index.lock file from .git folder and tried checking out that file again, then it is showing "segmentation fault".

Can anyone please guide me to the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There’s usually a lock file in the git folder. Check for it

Comment: When I delete the lock file and again try to checkout it shows segmentation fault, and lock file is created automatically again.

Comment: What version of git are you running? Other questions similar to this cite updating git as a possible solution.